# Error 500 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, thymeleaf

Tomcat gives error 500 when starting project `jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/index.html]")`

I checked the controller, configuration and everything seems to be configured correctly.

SpringConfig:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.user.package")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

ServletInitializer:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
     @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{"/"};
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class FirstController {
    @GetMapping("/testing")
    public String testingPage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

I looked at other similar questions on stack overflow, watched a lot of videos on YouTube, just surfed the Internet and didn’t find anything useful. I just have to ask the question myself.

Comment: Look at the full stack trace - not just the part you have shown in the question. There _may_ be much more specific details provided. Add the entire stack trace to the question, also (as formatted, readable text). If the stack trace refers to a specific line and column where the error is triggered, remember that we cannot see your template file's line numbers, so tell us explicitly which line of the template that is.